# Network protocol for consistent mobile clients requests

Tags: http, mobile, tcp, protocols

Is there a protocol (or framework) that ensures that when a request fails, it fails on both the client side (iOS, Android, etc) and server side, and when it succeeds, successes on both sides?

The request might be completed on the server but because of dropped network connection, the client does not receive the response and thinks that the request failed.

Answer (score 0):

The [Post-Redirect-Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern can be adapted to this.  The post part is used to submit the request, and the redirected get will be to a "results" page where the client can acquire the status (in progress, failure, success. etc).

Obviously, a client should not conclude from a network problem that the request failed.  It should simply be prepared to wait and/or retry to obtain the status.

The interesting case is where the initial request submission is incomplete, i.e. nothing, not even the redirect  comes back.  This is where the adaptation comes in.  The initial data submission should be after the server has generated a transaction identifier that the client can use as an alternative for status requests. (E.g., a form with a static field "Please save and use this tracking ID for status inquiries".)

If your question was whether this fallback can be automated at the protocol level, the answer unfortunately is no.